# HTU21 read problem

Tags: pigpio, temperature

I try to read temperature values from HTU21 with pigpio, C code given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>

#define addr 0x40
#define rdtemp 0xF3
#define rdhumi 0xE5
#define wtreg 0xE6
#define rdreg 0xE7
#define rst 0xFE

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gpioInitialise() ;
    int handle = i2cOpen(1, addr, 0) ;
    i2cWriteByte(handle, rst) ;
    i2cWriteByte(handle, rdtemp) ;
    char buf[3] ;
    char *p ;
    p = buf ;
    i2cReadI2CBlockData(handle, rdreg, p, 3);
    uint8_t msb = buf[0] ;
    uint8_t lsb = buf[1] ;
    uint8_t check = buf[2] ;
    printf("msb %d \n\r lsb %d \n\r checksum %d \n\r", msb, lsb, check) ;
    unsigned int data16 = ( ( unsigned int ) msb << 8 ) | ( unsigned int ) ( lsb & 0xFC ) ;
    float temp = ( float ) ( -46.85 + ( 175.72 * data16 / ( float ) 65536 ) ) ;
    
    printf("Temperature %f C \n\r", temp) ;
    i2cClose(handle) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Result is a constant value, independent of real temperature variation... Why?

Comment: Who can tell! Have you considered the radical step of checking the return value of functions for error (as every pigpio example suggests, and programmers do as routine in any code)?

Comment: Program start shows that handle=0, msb=176, lsb=6, checksum=1. These values are constant, independent of temp variation. Is it possible because of i2c clock freq is very high? Can it be set manually in pigpio?

Comment: Anothe question: how to set i2c timeout with pigpio?

Comment: post another question that asks that